# How to remove a directory from URL with .htaccess..?

Tags: apache, url, .htaccess

Ok, I've read so many examples on so many sites, it gets really hard to understand what's going on when it seems there are dozens of way to do anything with .htaccess.

Anyway, here's my setup: I have 2 domain names **example1.com** and **example2.com**

example1.com is an add-on domain, so its root is in the subfolder /example1.com/ on my server. When I type www.example1.com, that's what I see: http://www.example1.com/  **That's perfectly fine.**

example2.com is a parked domain, it points to the same folder /example1.com/ .  When I type www.example2.com, that's what I see: http://www.example2.com/example1.com/  **I would like NOT to see the subfolder, I would like to see http://www.example2.com/** but have the same content served.

There must be a way to do this with htaccess. I Hope someone can help.

Thanks.

Comment: So, let me get this straight: if you enter just http://www.example2.com/ it gets redirected to http://www.example2.com/example1.com/? At that point, does it display the example1.com content just under that subdirectory?

Comment: It gets redirected to http://www.example2.com/example1.com/  -  So www.example1.com AND www.example2.com/example.com/ BOTH show the same content...

Comment: Well, it seems to me that in Apache server you need to make some adjustments for virtual server configuration to point to same directory. For me it is not clear why would you have two domains pointing to same content. One possible reason I could understand if you move from one domain name to other and for some time you need provide access to both.

Comment: If you moving from one domain to other then move _web site_ to new location and in place of old domain locate simple html _web page_ with brief message about move and redirect in a few seconds to new location. In this case a visitor will be aware about the move and can make new/update bookmark pointing to new _web site_.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an iframe (ie: A box that syndicates another web-page) and skip any hassle with htaccess. The results are indistinguishable.